# Odoo13 : How to move a root-field in TreeView

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo-13

I want to fix this ID field in my tree field. I tried using css and scss already, but its not working. The field was created in my addon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Odoo Community module to version 12 called `web_tree_resize_column` it does what you want, you can find it [here](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/12.0/web_tree_resize_column).

I hope this answer could be helpful for you.